# MS Report Service: how to set up my own class as a dataset?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to build some report. The problem is I cannot set up several sources for my table whereas I need to accumulate different data into 1 table. I've created class and put it in the same domain as my EF classes are. When I try to add new dataset the wizard sees and behaves as if I can add it it but the list "Available datasets" is not updated. What did I wrong? How could this problem be solved?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution but it looks very stupid (from the architectural point of view) - you just add several different tables as sources and then in the table refer to theirs fields as if they are field of one big table. For example:

```
Fields!DriverLicense.Value
Fields!BrokerName.Value
```

Whereas both of them belong to different tables.